# ellipsis expansion fyne NewVBox

Tags: go, fyne

I'm trying to create a Fyne vertical box with a series of buttons but can't figure out the basic mechanism. I think this is a Go question, not a Fyne question, something I don't understand about go.

Here is a minimal program to show what I mean:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {

    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Button List")

    btn0 := widget.NewButton("button 0", func() {
        fmt.Println("Pressed 0")
    })
    btn1 := widget.NewButton("button 1", func() {
        fmt.Println("Pressed 1")
    })

    btns := []*widget.Button{btn0, btn1}

    vbox := container.NewVBox(
        // does work
        btns[0],
        btns[1],
        // doesn't work
        // btns...,
    )

    w.SetContent(
        vbox,
    )
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

My understanding is that the argument `btns...` should produce the same effect as the list of arguments `btn[0], btn[1]`, but it apparently doesn't. If I comment out the lines

```
    btn[0], 
    btn[1],
```

and uncomment the line

```
    btns...
```

I get the error message

> cannot use btns (type []*"fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget".Button) as type
> []fyne.CanvasObject in argument to container.NewVBox

So, my newbie questions:

- whats going on here, i.e., why doesn't `btns...` work?
- what should I be using as the argument to `NewVBox` instead?

Comment: it's not actually an ellipsis. it's the spread token. See also [variadic parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you're wanting to do here you need to modify the slice of `*widget.Button` to be a slice of [fyne.CanvasObject](https://pkg.go.dev/fyne.io/fyne/v2@v2.1.0#CanvasObject).

When spreading into a variadic parameter like this, the types have to match exactly to what the variadic parameter is expecting. This means the type needs to be the interface itself and not a type that implements the interface.

In your case, the following will work:

```golang
btns := []fyne.CanvasObject{btn0, btn1}
vbox := container.NewVBox(btns...)
```

Comment: Thanks! I regard this as a go-gotcha (along with how the iteration variable in a for loop ends up being the last value in certain circumstances). I somehow doubt that these are the only two things that would surprise a programmer familiar with other languages, so as a sort of follow-up question: Is there is a list of such "features", and if so, where?